# How can I invoke a function after two or more $scope events have been received?

Tags: angularjs

For example, let's assume I need to run a function after receiving two events "eventA" and "eventB". What I usually do is to declare for each event a boolean variable, set the variable to true when the event is received, and ask if the other variable is true to run the function:

```
var a = false, 
    b = false;

$scope.$on("eventA", function(){
    a = true;
    if (b)
        performTask();
});

$scope.$on("eventB", function(){
    b = true;
    if (a)
        performTask();
});

var performTask = function() {
    /* do something... */
};
```

This gets more complex if there are three or more events. Is there a design pattern to handle these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $q promises.

```
var dfdATask= $q.defer();
var dfdBTask= $q.defer();

$scope.$on("eventA", function(){
    // whatever this function does
    dfdATask.resolve(true);//or pass a value
});

$scope.$on("eventB", function(){
    //whatever this function does
    dfdBTask.resolve(true);//or pass a value
});

$q.all([dfdATask.promise, dfdBTask.promise]).then(function(){
    //be sure to pass in an array of promises
    //perform task
})
```

Answer (score 1):

## active polling using $scope.$watch:

One way to do this:

```
var a = false, b = false;
$scope.$on("eventA", function(){ a = true; });
$scope.$on("eventB", function(){ b = true; });
$scope.$watch(
   function() { return a && b; },
   function(newval, oldval) {
      if (newval) { performTask(); }
   }
);
```

one step further:

```
var events = { a: false, b: false };
$scope.$on("eventA", function(){ events.a = true; });
$scope.$on("eventB", function(){ events.b = true; });
$scope.$watch(
   function() {
      var result = true;
      for (var key in events) {
         result = result && events[key]; 
      }
      return result;
   },
   function(newval, oldval) {
      if (newval) { performTask(); }
   }
);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5NrOhTwblMCCCoKncVAW?p=preview

Be sure to read the [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) and check the **"Scope $watch Performance Considerations"** section.

## regular callback:

```
var events = { a: false, b: false };
function checkIfPerfomTask() {
   for (var key in events) {
      if (!events[key]) { return; }
   }
   performTask();
}
$scope.$on("eventA", function(){ events.a = true; checkIfPerfomTask(); });
$scope.$on("eventB", function(){ events.b = true; checkIfPerfomTask(); });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5NrOhTwblMCCCoKncVAW?p=preview

## with one promise, $q.defer():

```
var events = { a: false, b: false };
var shouldPerform = $q.defer();
function checkIfPerfomTask() {
   for (var key in events) {
      if (!events[key]) { return; }
   }
   shouldPerform.resolve();
}

$scope.$on("eventA", function(){ events.a = true; checkIfPerfomTask(); });
$scope.$on("eventB", function(){ events.b = true; checkIfPerfomTask(); });
shouldPerform.promise.then(performTask);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5NrOhTwblMCCCoKncVAW?p=preview

## with multiple promises...

Already been covered by multiple answers.

Comment: Nice use of `$watch`!

Comment: sometimes you need to use `$watch` for scope property changes; so if you are already using the `$digest` cycle, I don't see the problem. Point me to docs explaining **HOW** this is wrong and sure maybe I'll get convinced.

Comment: I can't they don't explicitly say that this is wrong heck sometimes they even allow it (ngModel) but if I don't have to poll I won't

Comment: I personally prefer avoiding watches because it is part of every single _digest_ cycle. There are enough watches registered already because of your _ngModel_ attributes, template expressions and ng- directives. And so as your app gets larger, for performance considerations, you may want to avoid watches. There is nothing wrong with watches as such though.

Answer (score 1):

So theory wise if you only want to execute this magical action after you've received these two events have been called at least once then you probably want to use promises.

```
app.controller('ExampleOneController', [
    '$log',
    '$scope',
    '$q',
    '$rootScope',

    function ($log, $scope, $q, $rootScope) {
        $scope.anotherAction1FiredCount = 0;

        var aDeferred = $q.defer(),
            bDeferred = $q.defer();

        $scope.$on('e-1-a', function () {
            $log.log('Fired e-1-a');
            aDeferred.resolve();
        });

        $scope.$on('e-1-b', function () {
            $log.log('Fired e-1-b');
            bDeferred.resolve();
        });

        $q.all([aDeferred.promise, bDeferred.promise]).then(function () {
            $log.log('Fired another action 1!');
            $scope.anotherAction1 = 'Hello World 1!';

            $scope.anotherAction1FiredCount++;
        });
    }
]);
```

That being said usually I want to execute everytime two things happen so I tend to 'reset' my promises.

```
app.controller('ExampleTwoController', [
    '$log',
    '$scope',
    '$q',

    function ($log, $scope, $q) {
        $scope.anotherAction2FiredCount = 0;

        var aDeferred = $q.defer(),
            bDeferred = $q.defer();

        $scope.$on('e-2-a', function () {
            $log.log('Fired e-2-a');
            aDeferred.resolve();
        });

        $scope.$on('e-2-b', function () {
            $log.log('Fired e-2-b');
            bDeferred.resolve();
        });

        var wait = function () {
            $q.all([aDeferred.promise, bDeferred.promise]).then(function () {
                $log.log('Fired another action 2!');
                $scope.anotherAction2 = 'Hello World 2!';
                $scope.anotherAction2FiredCount++;

                aDeferred = $q.defer();
                bDeferred = $q.defer();
                wait();
            });
        };
        wait();
    }
]);
```

[Here's the working plunker!](http://plnkr.co/edit/3s6mCxfFkUV6npRdhSO4?p=preview)

> Promises are life.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are meant for your use case. But since you mentioned you were looking for a design pattern, I'll put down one way to do this using the Observer pattern.

You can check out this live Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Oqn2TAGTr7NLYZd9ax1?p=preview

Has an angularjs service that handles the logic for tracking events and calling the final action.

The controller simply defines your events, the final event and registers them with your service.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, EventService) {
  var events = [];

  ... //define events

  EventService.registerEvents(events);
  EventService.registerEventsCallback(finalEvent); //the observer

});
```

The service makes this work by removing a called event from the events list upon first execution.

```
app.factory('EventService', function(){

  var events = [];
  var finalEvent;

  var eventsCallback = function(){
    if(!events.length){
      finalEvent();
    }
  }

  var resolveEvent= function(event){
      var eventIndex = events.indexOf(event);
      if(eventIndex>=0){
        events.splice(eventIndex,1);
      }
  }
  return{
    registerEvents: function(eventsList){
      events = angular.copy(eventsList);
    },
    registerEventsCallback: function(event){
      finalEvent = event;
    },
    publishEvent: function(event){

      event();

      resolveEvent(event);

      eventsCallback();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Not that I think design patterns are wrong but I don't think they should be forced or always used when looking at a new problem (sidenote)

Comment: Yes that can always end up being a trap. However, quite many times I have come up with programming solutions only to later find out there is a name given to the solution under the bracket of what we know are design patterns. And so, if design patterns are regarded a tool of communication rather than a silver bullet, the trap can be averted by the parties involved.

Comment: The philosophy is good. But this implementation is very sphagetti IMHO. - This can easily be broken if i register a different event under the same scope or anywhere else. - Remember factories are singleton you cannot really reuse this because you have a global event object, i may have many components in a page each probably having disconnected set of events. - Really? storing in an array without really having any map and i need to keep track of index, much worse than a magic string(or i otherwords an event name) that associate an event to its callback.

Comment: As simple example that can easily break. http://plnkr.co/edit/dD3lJjwnuC8shX2CRjsP?p=preview